# Fill in values on stepped data hierarchy

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there an elegant/tidy way to fill in the data if there are non-null values to the right? I have a wonky work-around but wanted to know if there was a nice `dplyr` way to do this.

```r
actual <-
  tibble(
    a = c("A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA),
    b = c(NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "C", NA, NA, "E", NA, NA),
    c = c(NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, "D", NA, NA, "F", "G"),
    d = c(NA, NA, NA, "C", "D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  ) 

desired <-
  tibble(
    w = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
    x = c(NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", NA, "E", "E", "E"),
    y = c(NA, NA, "B", "B", "B", NA, "D", NA, NA, "F", "G"),
    z = c(NA, NA, NA, "C", "D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give more context? It is not clear how and why column `x, y, z` are not fully filled. On what conditions do you format these columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr` together with `dplyr` like the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- actual %>%
  fill(a) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  fill(b) %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  fill(c) %>%
  group_by(c) %>%
  fill(d) %>%
  ungroup()

print(dat)
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
#    a     b     c     d    
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 A     NA    NA    NA   
#  2 A     A     NA    NA   
#  3 A     A     B     NA   
#  4 A     A     B     C    
#  5 A     A     B     D    
#  6 A     C     NA    NA   
#  7 A     C     D     NA   
#  8 B     NA    NA    NA   
#  9 B     E     NA    NA   
# 10 B     E     F     NA   
# 11 B     E     G     NA
```

Comment: @Edward I think as long as this hierarchical sequence remains (the latter one has more leading NA than and depends on the former one), it will work.

Comment: Yes - I guess so. It's unlikely that a row contains all NA. Sorry I deleted my previous comment. (the code won't work if the second row contains all NA). Very quick solution btw :)

Comment: That is so much simpler than what I had come up with. Thanks for the quick reply!